# Create dropdown with directory contents

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the below script that loads a json editor. The path to the json file that should be loaded is stored in a php var called $filePath. This works well however instead of loading a pre-determined json file I would like to have a dropdown list of all files in a specified directory ($dirPath) that the user can choose from. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php global $filePath, $dirPath; ?>
<script>

    // create the editor
    var container = document.getElementById('jsoneditor');
    var options = {
    mode: 'view', 
     modes: ['code', 'text', 'view'], // allowed modes
     onError: function (err) {
         alert(err.toString());
     },
     onModeChange: function (newMode, oldMode) {
         console.log('Mode switched from', oldMode, 'to', newMode);
     }
    };
    var editor = new JSONEditor(container, options);
    // set json
    document.getElementById('setJSON').onclick = function () { 
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
             'global': false,
             'url': "<?php echo $filePath; ?>", 
             'dataType': "json",
             'success': 
             function (data) { json = data; } 
            });
        editor.set(json);
    };

</script>
```

Comment: whats in $dirpath?

Comment: Thats just a variable that contains the path of the folder I want to list.  
filePath = /mydata/myfile1.json
dirPath = /mydata

That folder would have several files and those filenames are what I want to list in the drop-down
    /mydata/myfile1.json
    /mydata/myfile2.json
    /mydata/myfile3.json